# CSV import only for certain amount then exceed data go into another table

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a problem here. I don't know how to give an appropriate question title. So here is my problem.

I have a set of csv data. Let's say 30 data. The condition is I want only 20 data goes to Table A and another 10 data goes to Table B.

Do you have any example on how to work with this logic? Can it be done by combining while loop and if statement? By the way, it is a PHP and I'm still a newbie programmer. Hopefully someone can help me. Thank you.

Edited:
My current code

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
{
    if($leftPax > 0)
    {
        $registrantBean = new z_EventRegistrants();
        $registrantBean->last_name = $data[1];
        $registrantBean->id_no = $data[0];
        $registrantBean->phone_mobile = $data[2];
        $registrantBean->email1 = $data[3];
        $registrantBean->gender = $data[4];
        $registrantBean->date_of_birth = $data[5];
        $registrantBean->age = $data[6];
        $registrantBean->race = $data[7];
        $registrantBean->z_eventregec5erations_ida = $registrationBean->id;
        $registrantBean->save();
        $count++;
        error_log(print_r($_REQUEST['session'], 1));
        foreach($_REQUEST['session'] as $aid=>$sid)
        {
            $attendanceBean = new z_EventAttendances();
            $attendanceBean->name = $registrantBean->last_name;
            $attendanceBean->z_eventsessions_z_eventattendancesz_eventsessions_ida = $sid;
            $attendanceBean->z_eventactivities_z_eventattendances_1z_eventactivities_ida = $aid;
            $attendanceBean->z_eventregistrations_z_eventattendancesz_eventregistrations_ida = $registrationBean->id;
            $attendanceBean->z_eventregistrants_z_eventattendancesz_eventregistrants_ida = $registrantBean->id;
            $attendanceBean->save();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $waitlistBean = new z_EventWaitlists();
        $waitlistBean->name = $data[1];
        $waitlistBean->save();
    }
}
```

What I want, the 20 data will go to z_EventRegistrants and the other 10 will go to z_EventWaitlist.

Comment: What have you tried so far? show your code.

Comment: @CodeGodie i have edited. code is there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to asked some where in your code if the $count == 20 
`

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
{

        if($leftPax > 0 && $count <= 20)
        {
            $registrantBean = new z_EventRegistrants();
            $registrantBean->last_name = $data[1];
            $registrantBean->id_no = $data[0];
            $registrantBean->phone_mobile = $data[2];
            $registrantBean->email1 = $data[3];
            $registrantBean->gender = $data[4];
            $registrantBean->date_of_birth = $data[5];
            $registrantBean->age = $data[6];
            $registrantBean->race = $data[7];
            $registrantBean->z_eventregec5erations_ida = $registrationBean->id;
            $registrantBean->save();
            $count++;
            error_log(print_r($_REQUEST['session'], 1));
            foreach($_REQUEST['session'] as $aid=>$sid)
            {
                $attendanceBean = new z_EventAttendances();
                $attendanceBean->name = $registrantBean->last_name;
                $attendanceBean->z_eventsessions_z_eventattendancesz_eventsessions_ida = $sid;
                $attendanceBean->z_eventactivities_z_eventattendances_1z_eventactivities_ida = $aid;
                $attendanceBean->z_eventregistrations_z_eventattendancesz_eventregistrations_ida = $registrationBean->id;
                $attendanceBean->z_eventregistrants_z_eventattendancesz_eventregistrants_ida = $registrantBean->id;
                $attendanceBean->save();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $waitlistBean = new z_EventWaitlists();
            $waitlistBean->name = $data[1];
            $waitlistBean->save();
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: i think not like this. because i want automatically do. the situation like this.
a set of csv is 30 data. but registration limit only for 20 person. so it will import 20 data into registration. after that the rest of data will got into wait list.